# IPv6 masquerading on linux

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6, nat, pfsense

## Problem

I have following setup to access both IPv4 and IPv6 internet

```
[RockyLinux 9                ]                         [pfSense                     ]
[GRE IPv6: fdfe:xxxx::1/64   ]<------ GRE tunnel ----- [GRE IPv6: fdfe:xxxx::1000/64] <---[LAN(IPv4 and IPv6)]
[Public IPv6: 2a0c:xxxx::xxxx]                                        |
              |                                                       |
              |                                                       |
              V                                                       V
        [IPv6 Internet]                                         [IPv4 Internet]
```

General idea is to pass IPv6 network traffic via pfSense to RockyLinux machine and then RockyLinux should masquerade this traffic and route it to public IPv6 network(which is not available to pfSense). Though currently I am able only to access from both pfSense and LAN to RockyLinux machine. If I try connecting to any public IPv6 host RockyLinux responds with `ICMPv6: Destination Unreachable: Admin Prohibited`.

### Context

- GRE tunnel on RockyLinux is setted up with NetworkManager, though I have tried setting it up with `ip` command but it gave no changes
- `fdfe:xxxx::1` responds well from both pfSense and LAN network and all traffic to public IPv6 hosts is routed to it, so routing on pfSense and LAN is setted up correctly
- Public IPv6 addresses are accessible from RockyLinux and respond well
- Rocky Linux has IPv6 forwading enabled:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 2
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route = 1
```

## What have been tried

**NOTE:** In my `ip6tables` every chain policy both in default table and `nat` table is set to `ACCEPT`

- I have tried setting up a typical rule in `POSTROUTING`: `ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s fdfe:xxxx::/64 -j MASQUERADE` which gave no effect
- I cleaned-up `ip6tables` tried logging on different chains:

  - `FORWARD` in default table: logs all packets which should be forwarded
  - `PREROUTING` in `nat` table: also logs all packets
  - `POSTROUTING` in `nat` table: logs nothing of packets
- Also I have tried using `firewalld`:

  - `firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv6 source address=fdfe:xxxx::/64 masquerade' --permanent`
  - `firewall-cmd --zone=internal --add-interface=gre0 --permanent`

Though nothing of this gave any changes to behaviour: RockyLinux refuses to forward any IPv6 packets from `gre0` to `eth0` and responds back `ICMPv6: Destination unreachable: Admin prohibited` with any of above solutions

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to the IPv6 masquerading feature being disabled in your kernel. It is a build-time feature switch:
https://www.kernelconfig.io/config_nf_nat_masquerade_ipv6?q=&kernelversion=5.15.116&arch=x86
which is not set at least on the debian-based systems I have.
To check, search your kernel config for `CONFIG_NF_NAT_MASQUERADE_IPV6`.
Your kernel config is usually available at `/boot/config-$(uname -r)` or at `/proc/config.gz`. If the kernel config does not contain the flag `CONFIG_NF_NAT_MASQUERADE_IPV6`, you would need to get a different kernel or compile one yourself with that option enabled.

The arguably better solution (because that is how IPv6 is meant to be used, and you don't need a custom kernel for it, and there's no need to do NAT and keep track of connection state on RockyLinux)  would be to assign a globally unique IPv6 address/subnet to your pfSense. As pfSense is usually used as a router, I suspect that you don't just want the pfSense system itself to have IPv6 connectivity, but also the machines on the LAN behind it. If you are lucky and your ISP (for RockyLinux) does IPv6 "right", you could get a prefix (of prefix-length /64 or shorter) delegated for the LAN and route that prefix to pfSense, so that pfSense can advertise it on the LAN. Search for "IPv6 prefix delegation" to see how to set this up. Not all network managing tools support this, but at least `systemd-networkd` and `dhcpcd` do.

If you are unlucky and "just" get a /64 from your ISP, you could still take a smaller sub-network (longer prefix, i.e. /68) and use that for pfSense and the LAN behind it, but you would need to use DHCPv6 or static IPv6 addresses, as the standard mechanism of router advertisement doesn't work with smaller networks than /64.

If you are even more unlucky and your ISP just gives you a single IPv6 address (there are hosters of VMs for renting that do this, and maybe your RockyLinux is such an instance), you are either back to compiling your own kernel for IPv6 masquerading support, or you move to a different ISP for IPv6 (like tunnelbroker.net).

Comment: A single `/64` is not enough for “the way it’s meant to be used” routing, at least one additional address (the router, as visible from the outside) is required. It can be done, but requires quite some work.

Comment: @DanielB you're totally right. I edited my answer accordingly.